# Why is it not clearing my div? (Javascript & Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When clicking on a button my `testResults()` function is fired. It creates the `div`s as it should. I want the #parent div to be cleared everytime the button is clicked. BUT it only does it the first time you click. The second time you click the `#parent` `div` is not cleared and the new `div`s are just appended.

This is my code:

```js
// DECLARATIONS
var searchActive = false,          
    emailAddresses = [],
    firstName,
    lastName,
    domainName;

// MAIN FUNCTION

function testResults (form) {
    // TRYING TO DELETE INNERHTML EVERYTIME SOMEONE CLICKS

    // VARIANT 1 --> NOT WORKING
    document.getElementById("parent").innerHTML = "";

    // VARIANT 2 --> NOT WORKING
    $( "#parent" ).html("");

    // VARIANT 3 --> NOT WORKING ASWELL
    var div = document.getElementById('parent');
    while(div.firstChild){
        div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
    }

    // CHECK IF ALL FIELDS ARE FILLED IN (INCOMPLETE)
    if (!form.firstName.value) {
        alert("Bitte fülle alle Felder aus!");
    }
    if (! form.lastName.value) {
        alert("Bitte fülle alle Felder aus!");
    }
    if (! form.domainName.value) {
        alert("Bitte fülle alle Felder aus!");
    }

    // SAVE VALUES FROM THE FIELDS
    firstName = form.firstName.value;
    lastName = form.lastName.value;
    domainName = form.domainName.value;

    // STRING MODIFICATIONS
    firstName = firstName.toLowerCase();
    firstName = firstName.replace(/ä/g,"ae").replace(/ö/g,"oe").replace(/ü/g,"ue");

    lastName = lastName.toLowerCase();  
    lastName = lastName.replace(/ä/g,"ae").replace(/ö/g,"oe").replace(/ü/g,"ue").replace(/ß/g,"ss");


    // ADD ADDRESSES TO ARRAY
    emailAddresses.push(firstName + "." + lastName + "@" + domainName);
    emailAddresses.push(firstName + "@" + domainName);


    // ITERATE OVER ARRAY, CREATE A DIV FOR EACH EMAILADDRESS
    for (i = 0; i < emailAddresses.length; i++) { 
        $( "#parent" ).append( "<div class='alert alert-info'>" + emailAddresses[i] + "</div>");
    }

}
```

Why is it not clearing the #parent div even though I have tried 3 different variants? The console is empty aswell.

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/zdeahcqc/

Comment: Can we see the `HTML`, or an online demo?

Comment: Does the browser console give any clues?

Comment: Try `$("#parent").empty()` instead of `$("#parent").html("")`

Comment: Here is a the demo: http://167.114.3.182/test/

Comment: The console is empty

Comment: put your demo code in jsfiddle

Comment: $("#parent").html("") - did not work aswell

Comment: jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/zdeahcqc/

Comment: It's because of the submit event of your form. Try to put your button out of the form or prevent submit event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not clearing the array.  emailAddresses = []; it's working fine http://jsfiddle.net/zdeahcqc/5/

```
        function testResults (form) {
 emailAddresses = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

The `div` **is** being cleared.

But you're not resetting the `emailAddresses` array each time the form is submitted, so the `emailAddresses` list keeps getting longer (first it holds 2 emails, then 4, then 6) – you're appending all these email addresses to the `div`.

Just add `emailAddresses = []` at the beginning of your function.

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/zdeahcqc/6/

Answer (score 0):

Use `empty()` function instead - See http://api.jquery.com/empty/.

Secondly, you need to reset the `emailAddress` array that is being used to track the values.  In the final loop it uses the previous values.

Also, you do not need use 3 separate if statements to indicate all fields are required, one check covering all three would suffice.

Try the following

```
function testResults (form) {
    $("#parent").empty(); // Clear all existing entries
    emailAddresses = []; // Empty the array

    // CHECK IF ALL FIELDS ARE FILLED IN (INCOMPLETE)
    if (! form.firstName.value || form.lastName.value || form.domainName.value) {alert("Bitte fülle alle Felder aus!"); return false;}

    // SAVE VALUES FROM THE FIELDS
    firstName = form.firstName.value;
    lastName = form.lastName.value;
    domainName = form.domainName.value;

    // STRING MODIFICATIONS
    firstName = firstName.toLowerCase();
    firstName = firstName.replace(/ä/g,"ae").replace(/ö/g,"oe").replace(/ü/g,"ue");

    lastName = lastName.toLowerCase();  
    lastName = lastName.replace(/ä/g,"ae").replace(/ö/g,"oe").replace(/ü/g,"ue").replace(/ß/g,"ss");


    // ADD ADDRESSES TO ARRAY
    emailAddresses.push(firstName + "." + lastName + "@" + domainName);
    emailAddresses.push(firstName + "@" + domainName);


    // ITERATE OVER ARRAY, CREATE A DIV FOR EACH EMAILADDRESS
    for (i = 0; i < emailAddresses.length; i++) { 
        $( "#parent" ).append( "<div class='alert alert-info'>" + emailAddresses[i] + "</div>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it's correct but it's not the main problem. His onClick event is not fired because the form is submited first.

Comment: But I have <input type="button"> not "submit" T00rk , so that shouldn't be the case? Or am I wrong?

Comment: I tried to put your button outside the form and it works http://jsfiddle.net/zdeahcqc/4/

Comment: @kristian I have updated the code. You are not clearing the previous array.